# Did the theft of Syamantaka happen before of after the Mahabharata war?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

I am trying to ascertain the timeline of the stealing and recovery of Syamantaka and whether it happened before or after the Mahabharata war. Is this mentioned in any of the scriptures ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Syamantaka mani episode happened before Mahabharata war.**

[After Syamantaki mani episode, Satyabhama became wife of Krishna.](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/56/)

In [Mahabharata vana parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03231.htm), when Pandavas are in the forest, [Krishna visits them along with his wife Satyabhama](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03231.htm). So by this time, the syamantaka episode must have occurred.

Hence the conclusion.